# Chinese characters unable to get with Beutifulsoup4 in python3.x on windows OS

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-crawler, urlencode, url-encoding

My python version is 3.6.3. and my OS is WIN7.
I'm now working on extracting Chinese characters from a website below:
https://crl.ptopenlab.com:8800/poem/show?3&%25E5%258F%2591%25E7%2594%259F&A718FCB2-CE47-4649-BB46-0E09B169FD59

The elements I wanna extract are the characters embedded in the HTML codes below:

```
<div id="poemcontent" style="top: 82.4px;">
        <div id="title">发生</div>
        <div class="poembody">发情犹是梦</div>
        <div class="poembody">生意未能行</div>
        <div class="poembody">独坐青山下</div>
        <div class="poembody">还看白日明</div>

    </div>
```

My python codes are:

```
import urllib.request
res=urllib.request.urlopen("https://crl.ptopenlab.com:8800/poem/show?3&%25E5%258F%2591%25E7%2594%259F&A718FCB2-CE47-4649-BB46-0E09B169FD59").read()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(res,from_encoding="RTF-8")

body=soup.body
print(body.div.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents)
```

This code doesn't really extract the Chinese characters of exclusively. I just wanna check if the Chinese characters can be displayed properly. Unfortunately, the result isn't what I expected:

```
['\n', <div id="title"></div>, '\n', <div class="poembody"></div>, '\n', <div class="poembody"></div>, '\n', <div class="poembody"></div>, '\n', <div class="poembody"><img height="100px" src="static/images/write.gif" width="100px"/></div>, '\n']
```

If I extract the first item in the list, it displays like：

```
<div id="title"></div>
```

So that's the problem, there's no character displayed!

I've tried to extract Chinese characters on other websites using similar python codes the characters I crawled can be displayed normally.  None of them behaved like this one.

I changed several encoding methods, but that didn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the `poembody` content is because it's all generated via an AJAX call after the page is loaded.  Scraping the page will not retrieve this content.

You may be able to manually trigger the AJAX calls and collect their content, given the right inputs.  Specifically, call to `getPoems()`, which takes three arguments, `type`, `subject`, and `uuid`.  Those values in turn are parsed from the generic `window.location.search`.  See the `poem-0.0.76.js` file for details, linked in the `<head>` tag of the URL you provided.  With a little backtracking, it should be possible to piece everything together to get the poems you need.